# HTML table with rounded corners and gradient background

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with some CSS to style the table with rounded corners and a gradient background in the first row (for column headings) but come of the gradient is overflowing outside the rounded corner despite me specifying `overflow: hidden`;

HTML:

```
<table id="tblIncidentQueue" class="DataTable">
        <tr class="TableHeaderFooter">
            <td colspan="5">
                <strong>Show </strong>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpNumOfResults" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "10" Value="10" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "20" Value="20" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "50" Value="50" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "100" Value="100" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "All" Value="All" ></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <strong> entries</strong>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <img src="../images/Icons/Refresh.png" border="0" />
                <img src="../images/Icons/Down.png" border="0" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

CSS:

```
    .DataTable
{
    margin: 10px;

    -moz-border-radius : 10px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius : 10px; /* Linux browsers */
    border-radius : 10px; /* CSS3 compatible browsers */

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.TableHeaderFooter
{
    background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this in a specific browser? or in all browsers?

Comment: It's a lot easier for us to help you if you provide the generated HTML, preferably also with a demo (see: http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set property `border-radius` for those td elements in TableHeaderFooter.

```
.TableHeaderFooter td:first-child {
     border-radius : 10px 0px 0px 10px; /* rounds the top and bottom left corner */
}

.TableHeaderFooter td:last-child {
     border-radius : 0px 10px 10px 0px; /* rounds the top and bottom right corner */
}
```

Now you shouldn't see any overflowing backgrounds e.g. gradients (note that overflow property is useless in this case)

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Put all your background code from .TableHeaderFooter into .DataTable.
The edges will disappear.

```
.DataTable {
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius : 10px; /* Linux browsers */
    border-radius : 10px; /* CSS3 compatible browsers */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.TableHeaderFooter {

}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks, I don't want the gradient throughout the whole table though - there will be additional rows that I don't want the gradient on.

Comment: does it have to include ASP? You could get your result by doing an ul list instead.